# Which version of jQuery and jQuery Mobile work together?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, geolocation

I am working on a side project and would like it to be a mobile app with geolocation incorporated.  I'd like to start simple, though.

Which version of jQuery and jQuery Mobile work best together?  I've used some legacy versions on an iPad app, but I would like to know if more recent versions can work actually work together.

Alternately, am I better off just using jQuery UI or something like Twitter Bootstrap?  Any input on geolocation would be nice too.

Input is greatly appreciated, because I have big plans for this app in the next 6 months.

Many Thanks

Thanks to anyone that offered help, but I decided to build from scratch, using the latest version of jQuery, but no Mobile or UI

Comment: acorriding to you what "best" means ? in term of performance or stablity accross the browser ?

Comment: For now, just stability.  I hate picking apart other peoples' libraries.  I just want smooth integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Docs. jquery mobile 1.3.0 is the final and stable version.  I prefer stable version rather than nightly or alpha or beta builds.  which may have bugs in the early roll out phase.  [Jquery mobile.](http://api.jquerymobile.com/)

> jQuery Mobile 1.3.0 supports jQuery 1.7.0 to 1.9.1,

SO my answer would be : Use `Jquery Mobile 1.3.0` and `Jquery 1.9.1` libraries.