# how to fix conflict between jquery and jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have been searching for a resolution to a conflict I am having on a form but can't seem to work it out. I have a form that uses jquery 1.10.2 and jquery.mobile-1.3.2. I have an external script written in jquery that works beautifully if I disable jquery.mobile, unfortunately this kills most of the rest of the form.

I have tried to add noConflict to jquery but to no avail. Also, if I switch the order of the jquery and jquery.mobile the form break. sHow do I get the script to work with jquery.mobile?

html

```
        <div id="FieldBlank1" class="clonedInput">
                  <h2 id="reference" name="reference" class="heading-reference">Blank #1</h2>

<fieldset>
   <label class="label_QASample" for="QASampleID">QA Sample ID:</label>
   <input class="input_QASample" type="text" name="QASampleID" id="QASampleID" value="">       </fieldset>
 <div data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true" data-type="horizontal">
  <fieldset class="radio entrylist">
   <label class="label_radio" for="cCollection">Collection Method</label><br />
      <label><input type="radio" id="cradGrab" value="cCollectionGrab" name="cCollection" class="input_radio">Grab</label>
      <label><input type="radio" id="cradEWI" value="cCollectionEWI" name="cCollection" class="input_radio">EWI</label>
 </fieldset>
            </div> 
            <fieldset>   
   <label class="label_analysis" for="analysis">Analyte:</label>
        <select class="select_analysis" name="analysis" id="analysis" data-iconpos="left" data-icon="grid">
     <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">
                            Select</option>
           <option value="TN">TN</option>
           <option value="TP,NO2+3">TP,NO2+3</option>
           <option value="TP,NO2+3,NH3+4">TP,NO2+3,NH3+4</option>
           </select>  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
       <label class="label_preserve" for="preserve">Preserved</label>
    <select class="select_preserve" name="preserve" id="preserve" data-iconpos="left" data-icon="grid">
        <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">
                            Select</option>
           <option value="HNO3">HNO&#8323;</option>
           <option value="H2SO4">H&#8322;SO&#8324;</option>
                   </select></fieldset> 
       <div id="addDelButtons">
      <input type="button" data-theme="b" data-icon="plus" id="btnAdd" value="ADD FIELD BLANK">
       <input type="button" data-theme="b" data-icon="delete" id="btnDel" value="Remove the section above">
```

external script

```
  $(function () {
     $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
    var num = $('.clonedInput').length,
        newNum = new Number(num + 1),
        newElem = $('#FieldBlank' + num).clone().attr('id', 'FieldBlank' + newNum).fadeIn('slow'); 


    newElem.find('.heading-reference').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_reference').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_reference').html('Blank #' + newNum);

// text
    newElem.find('.label_QASample').attr('for', 'ID' + newNum + '_QASampleID');
    newElem.find('.input_QASample').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_QASampleID').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_QASampleID').val('');

// select
    newElem.find('.label_analysis').attr('for', 'ID' + newNum + '_analysis');
    newElem.find('.select_analysis').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_analysis').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_analysis').val('');

    // select
    newElem.find('.label_preserve').attr('for', 'ID' + newNum + '_preserve');
    newElem.find('.select_preserve').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_preserve').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_preserve').val('');

    // radio
    newElem.find('.label_radio').attr('for', 'ID' + newNum + '_cCollection');
    newElem.find('.input_radio').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_cCollection').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_cCollection').val([]);

     $('#FieldBlank' + num).after(newElem);

    $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', false);

     if (newNum == 5) $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', true).prop('value', "You've reached the limit");
   });

$('#btnDel').click(function(){
    // confirmation
    if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to remove this section of the form? Any information it contains will be lost!")) {
        var num = $('.clonedInput').length;
        // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
        $('#FieldBlank' + num).slideUp('slow', function () {
            $(this).remove();
            // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
            if (num - 1 === 1) $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', true);
            // enable the "add" button
            $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', false).prop('value', "ADD FIELD BLANK");
        });
    }
    return false;
           $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', false);
});

$('#btnDel').attr('disabled', true);
});
```

Comment: How can we possibly help you if we can't see any of your actual code?

Comment: Sorry I thought this to be kind of a general question. I will edit in code immediately.

Comment: Can you show us how you are including jquery, jquery mobile, and the shiny new script?

Comment: JQM enhance elements markup by adding extra elements. You need to go through your code without JQM and then with JQM and compare them. Most likely your selectors should be revised. Wrap your code inside `pageinit` event and remove `(function()` wrapping your current code.

Comment: <Head> <script  type="Text/Javascript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts.js"></script> <script> $(document).bind('mobileinit', function() { $.mobile.page.prototype.options.addBackBtn= true; $.mobile.page.prototype.options.backBtnText="Back"; $.mobile.page.prototype.options.backBtnIcon="arrow-1"; $.mobile.selectmenu.prototype.options.nativeMenu = false; }) </script> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

Comment: `arrow-l` not `1` for the back button. Can you setup a fiddle? It'll be helpful.

Comment: I have a fiddle and it works perfectly! It just doesn't work when you get all the other form elements in there. The form can be accessed at http://deq.mt.gov/wqinfo/WQLibrary/SiteVisit/index.html#chapter2

Comment: Cloning elements in JQM would cause many problems. You clone enhanced elements, they won't work. I just tested "add field blank" and the first problem appeared.

Comment: So how would I bypass the JQM for this section

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43154/discussion-between-omar-and-pja)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which version of jQuery and jQuery Mobile work together?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400436/which-version-of-jquery-and-jquery-mobile-work-together)