# Webpage hangs until clearing cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-appcache

I am developing an HTML5 game with jQuery. However, sometimes the page hangs up when loading (For now I only saw this happen on Chrome for mac). When it hangs, sometimes there is a string "waiting app cache" at the bottom. The webpage won't respond to any user mouse event during that time. The same will happen even if you reload the page. However, if you go to settings and clear cached images and files, the webpage won't hang on loading again.

I have no idea why this happen. There is no error in the console so I don't know where the problem could be. What's worse, when the webpage hangs it will be hard to even open the debug console. Any ideas or guesses as to why this happens? Thanks in advance!

Follow up, my javascript entry point:

```
$(window).ready(function() {
    middleLayerInitialize();
    initialize();
    addEventListeners();
});
```

Here is how I include jQuery:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
```

Comment: Might have to do with when your JS is running. Are you waiting for the document to load before executing your JS?

Comment: @HamzaKubba I have updated the post. The entry point is $(window).ready(). Not sure if this is what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

The two most common reasons for this are (1) you are including jQuery twice or (2) you are loading a ton of html and jQuery has to wait on your html to finish loading. If you download jQuery directly into your directory and include it in the HTML header, it may help.
http://jquery.com/download/

```
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Make sure that you aren't downloading it like below.

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

And make sure there is only one line including jQuery.

A final option (least likely to help). I don't know your setup, but try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // put all your javascript here.
});
```

instead of using (window).ready. I say this because you usually don't use (window).ready. You either use what I have written above or

```
window.onload=function(){SomeJavaScriptCode};
```

Comment: Thanks cgn. I have updated the post. I did download the jquery in local directory. The HTML file is about 40KB which I think is not large. I did included jQuery mobile and jQuery at the same time. Will that be the problem?

Comment: That's normal. You have to have jQuery to use jQuery mobile :) Maybe its a version issue. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400436/which-version-of-jquery-and-jquery-mobile-work-together